# Cannot publish .NET 4.7.2 project from console error MSB4062

Tags: c#, visual-studio, coreclr, .net-4.7.2

Trying to publish a console C# .NET Framework 4.7.2 project using this command

```
dotnet publish W-INST.csproj --configuration Release --runtime win-x64 --no-self-contained --framework net472 /p:PublishReadyToRun=true --output=bin\Publish\
```

But it get the error

> C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.402\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(4497,5):
> error MSB4062: The "Microsoft.Build.Tasks.GenerateTrustInfo" task could not be loaded from the assembly Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core, Version=15.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a.
> Confirm that the  declaration is correct, that the assembly and all its dependencies are available, and that the task contains a public class that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask.

I'm able to publish from VS 2022 gui.

Project-file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="15.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <ProjectGuid>{BE762AA2-11EC-4ED3-95D0-B871E6D1C20A}</ProjectGuid>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <RootNamespace>W_INST_W_KOPIA</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>W-INST_W-KOPIA</AssemblyName>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.7.2</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <FileAlignment>512</FileAlignment>
    <AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
    <Deterministic>true</Deterministic>
    <GenerateManifests>false</GenerateManifests>
    <IsWebBootstrapper>false</IsWebBootstrapper>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <StartupObject>Program</StartupObject>
    <ApplicationIcon>icon1.ico</ApplicationIcon>
    <PlatformTarget>x64</PlatformTarget>
    <LangVersion>7.3</LangVersion>
    <TargetZone>LocalIntranet</TargetZone>
    <BaseOutputPath>bin~NB\Build\</BaseOutputPath>
    <OutputPath>$(BaseOutputPath)\$(Configuration)</OutputPath>
    <AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>false</AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>
    <AppendRuntimeIdentifierToOutputPath>false</AppendRuntimeIdentifierToOutputPath>
    <PublishUrl>bin~NB\publish\</PublishUrl>
    <Install>false</Install>
    <InstallFrom>Disk</InstallFrom>
    <UpdateEnabled>false</UpdateEnabled>
    <UpdateMode>Foreground</UpdateMode>
    <UpdateInterval>7</UpdateInterval>
    <UpdateIntervalUnits>Days</UpdateIntervalUnits>
    <UpdatePeriodically>false</UpdatePeriodically>
    <UpdateRequired>false</UpdateRequired>
    <MapFileExtensions>false</MapFileExtensions>
    <OpenBrowserOnPublish>false</OpenBrowserOnPublish>
    <ApplicationRevision>1</ApplicationRevision>
    <ApplicationVersion>1.0.0.%2a</ApplicationVersion>
    <UseApplicationTrust>false</UseApplicationTrust>
    <PublishWizardCompleted>true</PublishWizardCompleted>
    <BootstrapperEnabled>false</BootstrapperEnabled>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug'">
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Release'">
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="icon1.ico" />
    <None Include="App.config" />
    <Compile Include="Program.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs" />
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.Core" />
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
</Project>
```

Comment: I'm not surprised. .NET Framework 4.7.2 is very old, and you're still using the old project format. I suggest to upgrade to 4.8 and change to SDK-style project formats. Anything else is basically unsupported.

Comment: But 4.7.2 is the only one you can be sure of run native on Win10 boxes (not require runtime update), that's why it is till valuable. Normally I target .Net 6 but this project just need to run easily on everything.

Comment: Don't use dotnet.exe for projects that target 4.x.  It is meant to support .NET5+ programs, ones that target coreclr.  Afaik there is no formal publish procedure for 4.x, beyond ClickOnce, we all simply used xcopy to copy the files in the Release build directory.

Comment: To publish from command line/console you should be using `msbuild` instead of `dotnet` for .net framework 4.x projects.

Comment: try to change csproj format to SDK, it doesn't require changing target framework version: https://codeopinion.com/migrating-to-sdk-csproj/

Comment: Hello, have you installed the Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core package? If installed try updating to the latest version or try another version